# How to add Custom Titlebar with Button on top of Tabs in Android

Tags: android, button, tabs, titlebar

I have a Tabhost in Android. I now want to know how can i put Custom Titlebar on top of it with button on right. Below is my code :

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                +++++++ +
+                +++++++ +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+           +            +
+           +            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

support.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TabHost>
```

Support.java

```
public class Support extends TabActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.support);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TestListView.class);
        spec = tabHost  .newTabSpec("some_things")
                        .setIndicator("Info")
                        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TestListView.class);
        spec = tabHost  .newTabSpec("top_things")
                        .setIndicator("Log")
                        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 85;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 85;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a drawable to set indicator

```
.setIndicator("Log",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_log));
```

you may also pass a seletor id to getDrawable().

here is a good [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)

Comment: The answer is totally irrelevant.